# jquery parse spring mvc object auto call toString

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jpa, object-to-string

I'm using JSP + MVC in web application. And I found that when jQuery parse a java object, it auto call Java's toString() method. Does there's any documentation to explain why?

example, JSP use department back from controller

```
${departmentList }
```

i can see toString() log in console.

but if i use

```
${departmentList.name }
```

it will only goto

```
getName() //(getter method).
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. It's Expression Language that does this.

What else would you want it to print?

See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html

Comment: i don't want to print anything. there's a bug to my own toString function, causing endless loop. I found this bug when notice jsp calling toString. Anyway, thanks for your reference. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the nature of expression language evaluation. when you use expression language it will search .(dot) in it if .(dot) found it will call getter of that properties other wise call toString() of that object

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing has nothing to do with jQuery.

```
${departmentList }
```

in your jsp is processed on the server side, not the client side. 
What the engine that processes jsp does in this case is perfectly logical, it calls `toString` just like System.out.println() would if you passed it `departmentList`

When however you use

```
${departmentList.name }
```

the engine that processes the jsp page will automatically can the `getName` method on the object